# Incorporating oc lazyload with gulp-angular

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular, oclazyload

How can I incorporate oc lazyload to work with [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) yeoman generator , Since running gulp will inject all the dependencies in the scripts folder. How can I configure oc lazyload to inject the dependencies  instead ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you need to do

- Remove references of dependencies from index.html
- Add dependencies for each project along with route using either

  ```
  <div oc-lazy-load="['scripts/controllers/about.js', 'scripts/services/helloservice.js']">
      <div ng-controller="AboutCtrl as about">
           Your html goes here
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Or you can add references in app.js file

  ```
  $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
  modules: [{
        name: 'helloWorldApp.contact',
        files: ['scripts/controllers/contact.js', 
                'scripts/services/contactservice.js']
        }]
  });
  ```

I have implemented the same with Grunt instead of Gulp. But it's alomst same. Checkout my article. https://routerabbit.com/blog/convert-angularjs-yeoman-spa-lazyload/

Comment: The thing is that i am using Future State Provider (https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future) in the same project , So that the states are created realtime , I still need to check if It will work the way i expect . Thanks to you .

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work. You can create a small project on Github with that & send me URL. I will experiment with it.